# How to find the lifetime of sodium atoms in the 3p using information on the spectral line width?

Tags: spectroscopy, energy

I am trying to find the lifetime of sodium atoms at the 3p state using the relationship between the spectral linewidth and the uncertainty principle:
$$ \Delta E \times \Delta t = h / 4\pi $$
The information I have is the full-width-half-maximum (FWHM) linewidth of the sodium atomic absorption spectrum $\lambda = \pu{9.2E-14 m}$. How would I use this equation to find the lifetime?

The atomic transition from ground 3s to excited 3p states has a wavelength $\lambda = \pu{589.0 nm}$.

I used the relationship
$$ \Delta E = \frac{h c \Delta \lambda}{\lambda^{2}} $$

Plugging in $\Delta \lambda = \pu{9.200E-14 m}$, then
$$ \Delta E = \frac{h \cdot \pu{3E8  m} \cdot \pu{9.200E-14 m}} {(\pu{589.0E-9 m})^{2}} $$

So using the uncertainty relationship, we have that
$$ \Delta t = \frac{h}{ 4 \pi \Delta E} = \frac{(\pu{589.0E-9 m})^{2}}{4 \pi (\pu{3E8 m s^-1} \cdot \pu{9.200E-14 m})} = \pu{1.000E9 s} $$

My attempt to convert the linewidth from unit of $\pu{nm}$ to $\pu{eV}$:
$$ E = \frac{hc}{\lambda} = \frac{\pu{6.626E-34 J s} \cdot \pu{3E8 ms^-1}}{\pu{9.200E-14 m}} = \pu{2.161E-12 J} = \pu{1.348E7 eV} $$

Comment: I find something in 10^-47 s. Am I wrong ? Does it make sense ?

Comment: @Maurice It is to be expected that the number will be much smaller than the literature value (17 ns), because the linewidth is smaller in the problem. However, I calculted $1 \times 10^{-9}$ s. Would you mind sharing how you calculated the time? Thank you.

Comment: The answer suggested in the comment as 10^-47 s is completely wrong. Your answer is in the right ball-park of ns. Make sure you don't round off anywhere until the end.  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/parlif.html

Comment: @M.Farooq How do you convert the linewidth from nm to eV? I tried $E = hc/ \lambda$ and changed the unit from J to eV, but the result is orders of magnitude away from the number on that website.

Comment: Your units must be inconsistent. If you are using $\delta$E in eV your Planck's constant must be in eV as well. Please show your calculations and steps in the original post and we can start from there.

Comment: @M.Farooq I updated my calculations for the linewidth and also how I got $1 ns$ as the lifetime. Would you mind checking both? Thank you.

Comment: @ferrin, Your calculations and approach are correct. Maybe you are not getting the exact result because the 589 nm is actually a doublet consisting of 588.9950 and 589.5924 nm. Your half-width information *in the textbook* might be different. So the half-width of each line is actually smaller because there is a separation between the two lines. Smaller half-width in terms of energy means longer lifetime. So if you happen to find true halfwidths you should get close to literature. What is the answer in the textbook? The ballpark of nanoseconds seems to be correct.

Comment: @M.Farooq Thanks for checking! That doublet argument could be the reason. I calculated the half-width myself from the previous question that asks to plot the absorption spectrum in Lorentzian distribution. And I set the center $\lambda = 589.5 \textrm{ nm}$. I also found this literature https://steck.us/alkalidata/sodiumnumbers.pdf where they reported a lifetime of $17 \textrm{ ns}$. Maybe I didn't get the correct half-width. The problem set will be returned next week probably, so unforatunely I don't have the answer yet. Thank you for your help though! It means a lot :).

Comment: @ferrin, you half widths must be slightly off because that is the only variable you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Half the fwhm has to be added/subtracted  to the central wavelength and then this change in wavelength converted to an energy. Thus the limits on the wavelength are $\lambda \pm \Delta \lambda /2) $ and the energy change $\Delta E=hc/(\lambda - \Delta \lambda /2)-hc/(\lambda + \Delta \lambda /2)$ Joules with $c$ in m/s and $h$ in J s. Plugging in the numbers gives a lifetime of $\approx 10^{-9}$, i.e. $1$ ns.

As a rule of thumb, lifetimes of excited electronic states are rarely less than $10^{-12} $s and if the transition is allowed, as in this case often of the order of nanoseconds to microseconds. If transitions are forbidden then the lifetimes can extend from microseconds to seconds.

Comment: Interesting that I missed $\Delta \lambda /2$. However, I don't recall seeing this as such. If $\Delta$E is uncertainity, what is the rigorous statistical basis of dividing FWHM by 2? It is not equal to the standard deviation for a Gaussian, Voigt or Lorentz profile.

Comment: FWHM is full width at half maximum so divide by 2 and then work out energy spread. The important thing is that $\Delta \lambda$ does not directly give the change in energy. FWHM is not 1/e of width so this will not give absolutely correct answer, however using width to get lifetimes is only really true if nothing interacts with system so it is more hypothetical than real. Anyway the OP  should only use the data in the question.

Comment: It seems that OP has full raw spectrum, he could have plotted the intensities vs. energy, and get the energy width and proceed as suggested in the answer. The key point was that FWHM/2 is not the true uncertainty in the statistical sense and division by two is an approximation. As you said it is more of a hypothetical scenario.